# Strange beahviours with texture drawing in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am drawing texture in opengl using Triangles and vertices 
when it is drawn it is something like this

[image: Texture on GLSurface view]

Problem is it is drawing same triangle on both sides?
what's the solution to this?
here is my code?

```
public float m_cameraX=26.036f;
public float m_cameraY=45.126f;
public float m_cameraZ=5f;
    private final float[][] vertData = {
        {
                25.457f, 45.534f, 3.0f, 
                26.595f, 45.534f, 3.0f, 
                25.457f, 44.718f, 3.0f, 
                26.595f, 44.718f, 3.0f 
};
    vertBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuffer.put(vertData[i]).position(0);
        loadtexture();
        vertBuffer.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, imgHandle);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mColorHandle, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Comment: You didn't set texture coordinates.

Comment: How can i set texture co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set texture coordinates. Check out these tutorials:

http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/
http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/